# What is the recommended way to point an npm package's imports to a specific directory?

Tags: npm, package, shared-libraries, package.json

I have an npm package structured as follows:

```
my-package
├── build
├── many.config.files
├── package.json
└── src
```

It made sense to put helper files such as config files and `scripts` into the root of my package.  Then it made sense to have a `src` file so that my source files wouldn't mix with all my config files.  Then it made sense to have a `build` directory where the built version of `src` would get populated (maybe some transpiling and minification happens, etc).

Now my `src` directory has various JS files and folders, all of which users of my library should be able to import.

```
src
├── file1.js
├── file2.js
└── utils
```

For example, `import utils3 from "my-package/utils/file3.js"` should work just fine for them.  They should *not* need to type `import utils3 from "my-package/build/utils/file3.js"` to import the file.

**What is the best practice for dealing with this situation?**

I have tried/considered various approaches:

1. Setting `"main": "./build"` in my package.json.  This did not resolve the import error for me.
2. Setting `"directories": {"utils": "./build/utils"}` in my package.json.  This did not resolve the import error for me.
3. Copying package.json into my build directory during build.  Then `npm publish`ing the build directory instead of the entire project.  This has the upside of only sharing the built code.  This has the downside that the built package will have information in its package.json that doesn't make sense because files/directories are missing/mislocated.
4. Something along the lines of `module.exports = require('./build')` in an index.js file.  This did not work either.

Comment: You can import everything in index.js of your main folder (src)and then export it from there. And then you will be able to import everything with the folder name (the main package name) instead of specific file name.

Comment: @MonikaMangal Perhaps you can elaborate / provide an example.  What exactly would "everything" include?